# List Box in Access with linked MySQL table

Tags: ms-access, listbox, linked-tables

I have an MSaccess database with 2 tables (`process` and `data_type`).  Each `process` can contain 0-many types of `data_type`.  Within access, I have a form that displays a process with a list-box,  **([see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBASc.png))**, that has all of the `data_types`.  The user can then check the `data_types` that each `process` has.

We are in the process of migrating the data from access to MySQL.  As part of that I've created a `process2data` table that links the `process` and `data_type` table.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to create a form in Access (we are still, for now, using that as our display engine) that accomplishes the same thing with the online data.

You can download what I'm trying to do [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwxv3mVUVjHiREplWTJ5LVQ3S2M/view?usp=sharing):

(For simplicity, I've put copies of the online data tables that are in mySQL as offline tables in Access.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multi-valued fields works only on MS-Access databases, to emulate we need to add VBA code and a table to store the values.

1. Create intermediate table, in this case I have created [ProcessList_DataType], the [checked] field will be used to include the data type, see picture:

[image]

2. Create a form for ProcessList and a subform for [Datatypes] and [ProcessList_DataType] combined tables. Don't forget configure the link master fields.

[image]

3. Add code to check the referenced values are present on intermediate table:

   ```
   Private Sub Form_Current()
       On Error GoTo ErrExit
       If Not IsNull(Me!ProcessID) Then
           sql = "INSERT INTO ProcessList_DataType(ProcessList,DataType) " & _
                 "SELECT " & Me!ProcessID & ",datatype_id " & _
                 "FROM DataTypes WHERE datatype_id not in " & _
                   "(SELECT datatype_id from FilterQuery " & _
                   " WHERE ProcessList = " & Me!ProcessID & " )"
           Set db = CurrentDb()
           db.Execute sql
           cnt = db.RecordsAffected
           If cnt > 0 Then
               NeedRefresh = True
           End If
       End If
   ErrExit:
   End Sub
   ```
4. Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much.  I think I have it working.  The only issue that that for a given process (i.e. Process2) the only datatypes that show up are the ones that are checked (i.e. DataType2, DataType3, DataType5, and DataType6).

Does the ProcessList_DataType table have EVERY possible combination of DataTypes and Process?  IF so, then I can check the ones that are active and that should solve my problem.  

I also can't see where I need your code. It seems to create the "full" table I described above, but I guess I can handle this on the input side of things.  

Thanks again!

Comment: When I back to office I can publish the .accdb file... and also: can you mark the answer as correct and/or upvote? (green mark at left corner top of this answer)